# Unity - Google Play plugin - nothing is working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, leaderboard

Nothing is working in unity.

I did a game before with a google play login and it worked fine  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Samer.BalloonHunter&hl=en

but in my current project the newest plugin doesn't work at all, https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Every time I had imported it, and followed the instructions step by step but .... it is not working.

Unity is showing me the content doesn't exist for PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

and yes of course I added  following code also:-

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
```

Weird...even though in my legacy project it's working all fine.

This is so tiring, why the new plugin doesn't work?

Comment: its depressing but almost everyone has to use the Prime31 plugins.  even they are not "super easy" to use, but you can get them working. note that **everything about PGS has totally changed** recently.  it's a nightmare.

Comment: don't forget you have to deal with **PlayServicesResolver** these days, since your old game.

Comment: It doesn't even work in an empty fresh project with no other plugins. It IS a nightmare.

Comment: Wait, what are the Prime31 plugins? are those different than the PGS official plugins?

Comment: Try to use previous version of "Unity Google Play plugin". I have the same problem after update to the latest version of "Unity Google Play plugin".

Comment: https://prime31.com are the main supplier of plugins for Unity projects, for many years now.  it's unfortunate to have to pay a few dollars, but it is one option.

Comment: @Naeim, I have even used the old Unity GP plugin that I have used in my first game, but when I have tried to compile my new game with it, it fails to find the old google services libs folder in the android SDK. After research I found out that google has totally changed the sdk structure so the old plugin doesn't compile anymore on my machine anymore :(.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had this issue with nothing working after updating the unity plugin it was because the android SDKs were not up to date.

Go into your Android SDK Manager and update your APIs.

Make sure the ones highlighted in yellow below are updated (tick them and click install). Also, make sure it's updated for your target version of Android (if in doubt update multiple of the latest releases).

[image: Android SDK Manager update]

Comment: I swear I did...but I will recheck again when I am home.

Comment: anyway, I gave up on it and used dreamlo for leaderboard instead, it is a primitive highscore leader board but it worked....but it's sooooo simple to implement.  If only google makes it that simple!